# How can I call the fragments in main activity to play video through images

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am trying to make an app in which I can click an image and it should open the video with the help of fragment. But I am confused with how to call the fragments in main java. Feel free for more suggestions and corrections.

My xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        //image view as per the frame required
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/i1"
            android:src="@drawable/arena_reaction"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:srcCompat="@android:color/background_dark" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/i2"
            android:src="@drawable/frequentflyer_diop"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/i3"
            android:src="@drawable/frequentflyer_tyus"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

My Java code, MainActivityJava

```
package com.video.rsingh;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.VideoView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
        setContentView( R.layout.activity_main );

        ImageView i1 = (ImageView) findViewById( R.id.i1 ) ;
        ImageView i2 = (ImageView) findViewById( R.id.i2 ) ;
        ImageView i3 = (ImageView) findViewById( R.id.i3 ) ;
    }

    // **Issue after this code, I am trying to call the fragements here**

    { //**How to call here**
        public void OnItemClick(ImageView) {
            Fragment myFragement = null;
            Class fragementClass;
            switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.i1:
                    fragementClass = FirstVideo.class;
                    break;
                case R.id.i2:
                    fragementClass = SecondFragement.class;
                    break;
                case R.id.i3:
                    fragementClass = ThirdVideo.class;
                    break;
                default:
                    fragementClass = FirstVideo.class;
            }

            **using try and catch here**
            try {
                myFragement = (Fragment) fragementClass.newInstance();
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace( R.id.myFragement );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What happened when you tried the above?

Comment: Welcome to SO. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask on how to ask questions that can be answered effectively.

Comment: @LarsH after onItemClick I am getting error like you need to use semi colon here, and myFragement is not getting accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Create a base class for your Fragments, and extend this class in all of your fragments

`public abstract class BaseFragment extends Fragment {
   public static BaseFragment newInstance(){}
}`

then in `OnItemClick` 
change `Fragment myFragement = null;` to `BaseFragment myFragment = null;` and assign it `myFragment = FirstVideo.newInstance(), myFragment = ThirdVideo.newInstance()`

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace( R.id.containerIdInLayout, myFragment);
```

Comment: I already have made base class for my all fragments, but I will try with your suggestion and get back to you.. By the way, what would you suggest for switch?

Comment: Can you please tell me where and how can I call my video view through url??

Comment: Where are the url and videoview located?

Comment: I have created different fragments for each videoview and declared them there